# How do I bind a Label to a property in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, properties, label

I have a content page "**AnimalPage**" with labels. I want to bind the labels.Text to the properties of a class so that the labels are automatically updated as the property values change.

The class is "**Animal**" which has two properties, **girth** & **length**. When either value is modified, a 3rd property "**weight**" is automatically calculated *(note: the code that triggers the calcuation is not shown below)*. When the **weight** property changes, I want the weight Label on the content page to update automatically.

Many of the examples I've found on Xamarin are XAML which I'm not using.

At the moment, when the page loads, an initial value does show up in the Weight label so it seems like the binding is correct, but when the weight property changes, the label is not updated.

I've put breakpoints in the code and the calcWeight method is being called and the weight property is changing, but weightCell.cellText does not change.

What am I missing?

```
public class Animal {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private double _girth;
    // when girth changes, save the value and trigger a re-calculation of weight
    public double girth { get { return _girth; } set { _girth = value; this.calcWeight(); } }
    private double _length;

    // same for length changes; save the value and trigger a re-calculation of weight
    public double length { get { return _length; } set { _length = value; this.calcWeight(); } }

    private double _weight;
    public double weight { get { return _weight; } set { _weight = value; } }

    public Animal()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
    public double calcWeight()
    {
        // formula for weight calculation goes here...
        ...
        this.weight = weight;
        return weight;

    }
}
```

The page which displays this class is as follows:

```
internal class AnimalPage : ContentPage
{
    private Animal animal { get; set; }

    public AnimalPage(Animal animal)
    {
        this.animal = animal;
        BindingContext = this.animal;
        var weightCell = new ResultCell(); // ResultCell is a custom ViewCell
        Binding myBinding = new Binding("weight");
        myBinding.Source = this.animal;
        weightCell.cellText.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, myBinding);
        ...
    }
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the ResultCell class which is just a custom ViewCell with two labels displayed horizontally.

```
public class ResultCell : ViewCell {
    public Label cellLabel, cellText;

    public ResultCell() {
        cellLabel = new Label();
        cellText = new Label();

        var cellWrapper = new StackLayout {
            ...
            Children = { cellLabel, cellText }
        };
        View = cellWrapper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your UI to automatically update when your data changes, your Animal class needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx), and you need to fire the PropertyChanged event whenever your weight property is modified or recalculated.  This event is what alerts the UI that it needs to refresh.

Comment: Yes this worked. I went by the example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

It makes sense but I've seen Xamarin examples where they don't inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged and it still works, so I'm very confused. The only thing I can think of is that they must have been inheriting from a Xamarin class that already had that implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Since this took me so long to figure out I thought I'd post the corrected Animal class in case this helps someone else.

```
public class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private double _girth;
    public double girth { get { return _girth; } set { _girth = value; this.calcWeight(); } }

    private double _length;
    public double length { get { return _length; } set { _length = value; this.calcWeight(); } }

    private double _weight;
    public double weight { get { return _weight; } set { _weight = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

public Animal()
{
    ...
}
...
public double calcWeight()
{
    // formula for weight calculation goes here...
    ...
    this.weight = weight;
    return weight;

}
}
```